# Simplification of geometric series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone please help simplify this series?

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\frac 12\right)^k$$

In general, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac 12\right)^k = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} =2.$$

However, I am confused with the $k$ in front of the term $k\big(\frac 12\big)^k$.
I understand if the problem is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\big(\frac 12\big)^k$. However, it is the $k$ term that I don't understand. The answer is suppose to be $2$.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Your index needs to start at $k=0$, not $k=1$.

Comment: Right, but I still would have that k factor. And I still can't simplify to 2.

Comment: This isn't a geometric series.

Comment: I swear. As often as this exact question gets asked, we could almost make a decent drinking game taking a shot for each time. :)

Comment: Then I am not sure what type of series it is. But this comes from a problem from my stats. class and I have to simplify it to 2.

Comment: $$\sum^\infty_{k=1}k(0.5)^k=x\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\frac{x}{1-x}\Bigg{|}_{x=0.5}=2$$

Comment: This variety of series is [arithmetico-geometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to solve like a geometric series:

$$
S_n = \frac{1}{2} + 2\frac{1}{2^2} + 3\frac{1}{2^3} + \dots + (n - 1)\frac{1}{2^{n - 1}} + n\frac{1}{2^n} \\
\frac{1}{2}S_n = \frac{1}{2^2} + 2\frac{1}{2^3} + 3\frac{1}{2^4} + \dots + (n - 1)\frac{1}{2^{n}} + n\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \\
S_n - \frac{1}{2}S_n = \frac{1}{2} + (2 - 1)\frac{1}{2^2} + (3 - 2)\frac{1}{2^3} + \dots + (n - (n - 1))\frac{1}{2^n} - n\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
$$

This gives:

$$
S_n - \frac{1}{2}S_n = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{i = n} \frac{1}{2^i}\right) - \frac{n}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i = 0}^{i = n - 1} \frac{1}{2^i}\right) - \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}
$$

We know the geometric sum: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_0^n \frac{1}{2^i} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2$, which gives:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2
$$

Answer (score 4):

We have the geometric series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}
$$
Differentiate to get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}
$$
Multiply by $x$, and plug in $x=\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $|x|<1$ and write $$f(x)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx ^{k-1} = x\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x ^k\right)' = x\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x ^k -1\right)'$$
$$=x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-1\right)' = x\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)
$$
$$=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$

In you case, $x=\frac12$, so we have the series $$f(\tfrac12)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\left(\frac12\right)^k=\frac{\frac12}{(1-\frac12)^2}=\boxed{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k &= \frac{1}{2} + 2 \frac{1}{2^2} + 3 \frac{1}{2^3} + 4 \frac{1}{2^4} \dots\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \dots \right) + \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + 2 \frac{1}{2^3} + 3 \frac{1}{2^4} + \dots\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \dots \right) + \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \dots \right) + \left(\frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \dots \right) + \dots\\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \dots\\
&= 2
\end{align*}